# Clear output cells of Jupyter notebooks from command line

Tags: git, jupyter-notebook, jupyter

Often working collaboratively on Jupyter notebooks, I think it would be a great feature the be able to clear all output cells for a collection of notebooks from the command line, e.g. before doing a git commit. However, I have not found such a command so far. Does it exist?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Take a look at [nbstripout](https://github.com/kynan/nbstripout).

Useful mainly as a git filter or pre-commit hook for users who don't want to track output in VCS.

Inspired from minrk's [gist](https://gist.github.com/minrk/6176788)

Answer (score 4):

Look into the pre- and post-save hooks from [Jupyter Notebook](https://jupyter-notebook.readthedocs.io/en/stable/extending/savehooks.html).

To use this, the steps would be:

**1. Find your config file:**

The default path is /home/user/.jupyter/).

```
>> jupyter --config-dir
```

**2. Copy paste the code below to the `jupyter_notebook_config.py` file:**

The jupyter_notebook_config.py can be found in the directory above.

The code is directly copied from [here](https://jupyter-notebook.readthedocs.io/en/stable/extending/savehooks.html).

```
def scrub_output_pre_save(model, **kwargs):
    """scrub output before saving notebooks"""
    # only run on notebooks
    if model['type'] != 'notebook':
        return
    # only run on nbformat v4
    if model['content']['nbformat'] != 4:
        return

    for cell in model['content']['cells']:
        if cell['cell_type'] != 'code':
            continue
        cell['outputs'] = []
        cell['execution_count'] = None

c.FileContentsManager.pre_save_hook = scrub_output_pre_save
```

**3. Restart your jupyter notebook**

```
>> jupter notebook
```

Note that there is a corresponding post-save hook, that creates a separate .py for the .ipynb. You can also commit the .py instead of the .ipynb. There are also options of converting the notebook to html to allow the output to be visualized.

Answer (score 4):

[clean_ipynb](https://github.com/KwatME/clean_ipynb) not only clears notebook outputs but can also format the notebook code by: running isort, running black, and clearing output.

Install simply by `pip install clean_ipynb`

Run it simply by `clean_ipynb hello.ipynb`

Comment: There are some issues when run with R notebooks with the default options.

Comment: I get UnicodeError using this. package uses some mechanism to read file which includes other encodings